# Get the sum for each SQL row

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have written the query bellow and the problem I have is that is obviously returning the sum for the whole table (All employees together) and I would want it to return the total sum per employee, would this be possible at all?

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
TotalAmount DECIMAL,
ExpenseCategory UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
EmployeeId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
CategoryName NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @temp

SELECT  SUM(dbo.ExpenseDetails.TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount,         
dbo.ExpenseDetails.ExpenseCategory, dbo.ExpenseDetails.EmployeeId, 
dbo.ExpensesCategories.CategoryName
FROM            dbo.ExpenseDetails INNER JOIN
                     dbo.ExpensesCategories ON 
dbo.ExpenseDetails.ExpenseCategory = dbo.ExpensesCategories.CategoryId
WHERE        (CONVERT(DATE, dbo.ExpenseDetails.DateAdded) < CONVERT(DATE, 
DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())), 23 - 1))) AND 
(CONVERT(DATE, dbo.ExpenseDetails.DateAdded) > CONVERT(DATE,
                      DATEADD(MONTH, - 1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, 
CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())), 23 - 1))))
GROUP BY dbo.ExpenseDetails.ExpenseCategory, dbo.ExpenseDetails.EmployeeId, 
dbo.ExpensesCategories.CategoryName

SELECT
EmployeeId,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE EmployeeId = [@temp].EmployeeId 
and ExpenseCategory = '6CC0F801-D295-4997-9D1F-3E5B2BE692ED') AS TotalFuel,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE EmployeeId = [@temp].EmployeeId 
and ExpenseCategory = '3E54C10B-ECBE-4B28-87A4-5A4E43AACDFC') AS TotalRail,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE EmployeeId = [@temp].EmployeeId 
and ExpenseCategory = '31CC43A4-80E6-4DD4-A28C-039F05AF62A3') AS 
TotalParking,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE EmployeeId = [@temp].EmployeeId 
and ExpenseCategory = '01250A30-3865-40D2-9E49-DA2B9898B1F4') AS 
TotalMileage,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE EmployeeId = [@temp].EmployeeId 
and ExpenseCategory = 'F4E4582D-DEDF-499D-BBC1-45003B865218') AS TotalEquip,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE EmployeeId = [@temp].EmployeeId 
and ExpenseCategory = '55F471C1-6E52-4898-8263-0B7684B78E7C') AS TotalPPS,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE EmployeeId = [@temp].EmployeeId 
and ExpenseCategory = '1EE0FC40-193F-4720-9143-0B61FFDE7B8D') AS TotalOther

FROM @temp GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM` with condition:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeId,
    TotalFuel = SUM(CASE WHEN ExpenseCategory = '6CC0F801-D295-4997-9D1F-3E5B2BE692ED' THEN TotalAmount END)
FROM @temp
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

Comment: Hello Mikhail, that worked fine, the only problem now is that it wouldn't let me group by employeeId, so i end up with duplicate rows.

Comment: I missed it. With `group by` you don't need `OVER`

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
EmployeeId,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE ExpenseCategory = '6CC0F801-D295-4997-9D1F-3E5B2BE692ED') AS TotalFuel,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE ExpenseCategory = '3E54C10B-ECBE-4B28-87A4-5A4E43AACDFC') AS TotalRail,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE ExpenseCategory = '31CC43A4-80E6-4DD4-A28C-039F05AF62A3') AS TotalParking,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE ExpenseCategory = '01250A30-3865-40D2-9E49-DA2B9898B1F4') AS TotalMileage,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE ExpenseCategory = 'F4E4582D-DEDF-499D-BBC1-45003B865218') AS TotalEquip,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE ExpenseCategory = '55F471C1-6E52-4898-8263-0B7684B78E7C') AS TotalPPS,
(SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM @temp WHERE ExpenseCategory = '1EE0FC40-193F-4720-9143-0B61FFDE7B8D') AS TotalOther
FROM @temp GROUP BY EmployeeId

Can you try this?
Usually when Group By is used it should be followed with "having" at the end. It should not be present in where condition
```

Comment: That would most definitely give me the total sum for the table.

Comment: Add Having condition in the end Group By EmployeeId Having EmployeeId = (or in condition)